# Is torus a symmetric space?

Tags: differential-geometry, homogeneous-spaces

Let $\Lambda$ be a lattice in $\mathbf{R}^{n}$. The flat torus $T:= \mathbf{R}^{n}/\Lambda$ is a homogeneous space. I have two questions:

1. Is $T$ a symmetric space?
2. If so, is it irreducible for any $\Lambda$?

If the explanation is too long to write, just citing the reference will nevertheless be very helpful.

Thank you in advance.

**Edit**: For 1. I meant global symmetric space.
For 2. If $T$ is a global symmetric space, is the isotropy representation irreducible for every $\Lambda$?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The word "any" is ambiguous here: Do you mean "some" or do you mean "every?"

Comment: Also, what is your definition of an irreducible symmetric space? (For instance, Helgasson uses one definition and in the answer below another definition is used).

Comment: Ok, it is better now. However, what are your own thoughts about the question(s)? What examples did you work out?

Comment: I think that for any $p \in T$, we can construct an isometric involution by multiplying $(-1)$ around $p$. More explicitly, $x \mapsto -(x-p)+p =-x+2p$. However, a torus contains many types of geodesics, in particular aperiodic ones that wrap up the torus. I do not know the image of a geodesic after the aforementioned involution.

Comment: What book on symmetric spaces have you read? If seems that you do not know an efficient definition of a symmetric space (it does not involve geodesics).

Comment: Ok, the efficient definition of a symmetric space $X$ is that it is a connected Riemannian manifold such that for every $x\in X$ there exists an isometry $s_x: X\to X$ fixing $x$, such that the differential of $s_x$ at $x$ is the map $-Id: T_xX\to T_xX$. One can then verify that such $s_x$ is indeed an involution and that it acts on every geodesic $c(t), c(0)=x$ by $s_x\circ c(t)=c(-t)$.

Answer (score 2):

One definition of a symmetric space is the existence of a (local) involution preserving the metric.  Since the lattice $\Lambda$ is invariant under the isometry $\lambda \mapsto -\lambda$, so is the torus (even globally).

If by "irreducible" you mean "indecomposable as a metric product", then the torus will be reducible if and only if the lattice is a "rectangular" lattice, i.e., spanned by a pair of orthogonal vectors.

Comment: The standard definition of a symmetric space requires  global involutions (the one of a locally symmetric space needs a local involution) with few more properties. Where did you see a definition of a symmetric space where only a local involution is required?

Comment: @MoisheKohan, the idea is that a space whose universal cover is symmetric should also be called symmetric.  That's my recollection; I would have to check my sources.  At any rate, here we have a global involution.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, I guess I was thinking of a "locally symmetric space" :-)

Comment: Ok, you were confusing locally and globally symmetric spaces. Also, Helgasson's definition of "irreducible" is different from yours. With his definition, flat symmetric spaces (of positive dimension) are never irreducible!

Comment: @MoisheKohan, Good point.  The OP should clarify what he means.  At any rate, I stated clearly which definition I am using.

Comment: Yes, I know, I already asked OP for clarity.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, could you possibly elaborate on your comment here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363317/systole-of-riemann-surfaces-of-genus-g#comment917410_363317 ? I would be very interested.

Comment: I completely forgot about it. I will take a look.